# Redis pubsub with authentication in vertx

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, vert.x

I am trying to use redis pubsub chanel vertex as follows but I keep getting

> NOAUTH Authentication required

Following is a example code snippet: I have configured redis password in the redis .conf

```
vertx.eventBus().<JsonObject>consumer(VERTX_EVENTBUS_PREFIX + ASYNC_RESPONSE_CHANNEL, message -> {

    log.debug("Vertx event bus consumer invoked");           
    });
}).exceptionHandler(t -> {
    log.error("Exception thrown from vertx event bus consumer", t);
});

// Subscribe to the redis async response channel
redis.subscribe( ASYNC_RESPONSE_CHANNEL, res -> {
    if (res.failed()) {
        log.error("Failed to subscribe to the async response channel. " + res.cause().getMessage());
    }
    if(res.succeeded()) {
        log.debug("Subscribed to channel");
    }
}).auth("redispasswd", null);
```

Comment: I found the Solution. I should have passed the credintials differently. I will edit the question to add the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong to set auth  at the point of subscription. it needs to be set in the RedisOptions object and needs to be passed to RedisClient at the inittialization.

```
RedisOptions redisCfg = new RedisOptions().setHost(redisHost).setPort(redisPort).setAuth(redisPassword);
RedisClient redis = RedisClient.create(vertx, redisCfg)
```